# after groupby, using agg, how to get one element on condition of other columns

Tags: pandas

I am using groupby to process many columns using different functions.

I have used only one column, but I can't choose element on condition of other columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'a':['A','C','E','J'],'b':[1,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1,1,1,1])
df.groupby(level=0).agg({
    'b':'sum',
    'b':select element from b where a = 'C'
})
```

The goal is using `agg` to get this:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x.loc[x.a=='C','b'])
df.groupby(level=0).b.first()
df.groupby(level=0).b.sum()


    f   first   sum
1   2    1       10
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what output you want for `df`? Your description of what you want the code to do is unclear.

Comment: Have added it, thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not use agg with multiple columns.  Agg is to aggregate values of a single column, if you must have conditions based on a separate column, you need to use apply.

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.loc[x.a =="C", 'b'].values[0], 
                                               x.b.iloc[0], 
                                               x.b.sum()], index=['f','first','sum']))
```

Output:

```
   f  first  sum
1  2      1   10
```